# Pass NgRx Action as a param to a function: which types to use?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, ngrx

In my Effects, I use the following construction.

There are a few lines of code for the catchError to make sure that:

1. It's handled by the state/store
2. It's passed forward for the global error handler / Interceptors

```
getItems$ = createEffect((): Observable<Action> => {
  return this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemActions.getItem),
    exhaustMap(() => {
      return this.apiClient.getItems().pipe(
        map((response) => ItemActions.getItemsSuccess({ response })),

        catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) =>
          of(EMPTY).pipe(
            tap(() => this.store.dispatch(ItemActions.getItemsFailure({ exception }))),
            switchMap(() => throwError(() => exception)),
          ),
        ),

      );
    }),
  );
});
```

Since it uses 5 lines of (mostly duplicate) code each time I want to handle error like this, I pass it to the following method:

```
handle(action: Function, error: HttpErrorResponse, props?: object): Observable<never> {
  return of(EMPTY).pipe(
    tap(() => this.store.dispatch(action({ exception: error, ...(props && { ...props }) }))),
    switchMap(() => throwError(() => error)),
  );
}
```

So catchError now looks like:

```
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.errors.handle(ItemActions.getItemsFailure, error)),
```

---

It works, but:

1. **What is the proper type of action (Function works, but not what I'm looking for)**
2. **What is the proper type of props (object works, *but it should only allow props defined for the given action*)**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `Action` or `ActionCreator` for this
2. This is a bit harder, I think it would make more sense to create the action in the effect and pass its instance to handle: `catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.errors.handle(ItemActions.getItemsFailure(error))),`